# Best way to make cross-platform apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cross-platform

My question is: what is the best/easiest way to make cross-platform apps/games? iOS and Android - and Windows Phone if possible.

I have read about many different ways. HTML5 and JavaScript - and then just the overall implementation for the specific platforms. I have read about some 'converting tools' - fx Intel Porter Tool. And names like PhoneGap, Intel XDK, Appcelerator and Mosync and many others are showing up.

So I'm just all confused.. What would you prefer?

I'm not completely new in iOS programming, but not that much experienced either. I have made a few apps and games. Else I have a little experience with HTML and CSS. But I have never been working with HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm also aware that native platform specific apps is better that hybrid apps. But after all this I would love to hear from you : what do you prefer or not? :-)

Comment: There are quite popular cross-plateform solutions. I'd suggest you get one with a language you "master".

Comment: I would love to. But I think they are almost always build up on HTML5 and JavaScript? Can I make it with objective-C (xcode iOS programming)?

Comment: If I remember well Xamarin works with C# for example.

Comment: Anyone know what http://scribbleton.com was made with? It feels  nice on OSX and has Linux and Windows too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer- [**Which Cross Platform Mobile Development Platform Should You Choose**](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/07/01/cross-platform-mobile-development/)

You can read this document and choose whatever you feel comfortable to use. If you are using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript then you can use phonegap in my opinion but let it be refer above site you will get basic idea and so that you can choose whatever which you feel simple.

Answer (score 2):

For making Apps I think HTML5 alternatives like PhoneGap could be the easiest way, also you can take al look at [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/) for native cross-platform Apps, but you need to get a paid license to use it in a real project and, if you don't, you should learn C#.

In the case of making games, I have tried different platforms and I think [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is the easiest and fastest way to create cross-platform quality games, even for simple 2D games, and you can do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Just for future reference, the javascript in unity is different from web javascript. C# is just as straightforward (if not more), and has wider support / tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The best is Phonegap or Titanium (more powerful for me) http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium 
You should use the one you feel more comfortable. And with xcode and objective-c you can work with html-css-js but never export cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5/JavaScript.
Then use [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) to target desktop systems and [coccoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) or [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com) to target apps.